# How do I resize my text to fully fit a grid cell in WxPython? I'm having problems getting to my Attributes

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm using wxPython to create a GUI frontend to describe a sudoku puzzle.
On resize events, I'd like to grow or shrink my font so each digit takes up its entire cell.

From what I've found so far, I want to manipulate the attributes of the grid cells.
I'm a little confused about how attributes get managed, especially when smart pointers showed up, and how whole-grid vs row-specific vs cell-specific attrbutes work - but I'm not even to those problems yet.

```
def OnSize(self, event):
    //...
    for row in range (0, sudoku_9x9grid.rowscols):
        for col in range (0, sudoku_9x9grid.rowscols):
            attr = self.GetTable().GetAttrPtr(row, col, default)
            font = attr.GetFont()
            font.SetPixelSize(wx.Size(0, int(0.9 * size.GetHeight())))
            attr.SetFont(font)
    //...
```

The attr = self.GetTable()... line fails at runtime.

self is an instance of a class derived from wx.grid.Grid.  I thought the way I got to attributes was to call Grid's GetTable() function, which should return a wx.grid.GridTableBase object, and GridTableBase has the GetAttrPtr function.

But the documentation gets weird here.  GridTableBase has a "see-also GridStringTable" link on its [API page](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.grid.GridTableBase.html).  And lo and behold, self.GetTable() is returning me a GridStringTable, *which is not derived from GridTableBase*, and does not have a GetAttrPtr() member.

So, how do I get at the attributes of my cells in order to manipulate them?

Comment: `wx.Grid` has both `GetCellFont` and `SetCellFont` functions, which remove the need to charge off into the guts of the table. Ref: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.grid.Grid.html#wx.grid.Grid.SetCellFont

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's only a typo. The docs state following enums for the kind (GridCellAttr.wxAttrKind) attribute ([see here](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.grid.GridCellAttr.AttrKind.enumeration.html)):

```
Any
Cell
Row
Col
Default
Merged
```

So try to write ***Default*** instead of ***default***.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't look like that's it.  I switched the case to Default, and am still getting the same exception: "Message='GridStringTable' object has no attribute 'GetAttrPtr'"

Comment: Ahh. Missed that. At least I think I saw that the method existed (as you tried) in the docs.